# Trouble wiring a double row of droppers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

The problem seems simple enough.  I want to power a double row of droppers.  My idea was to redstone wire it this way:

[image]

Take a double decker row of droppers, and run redstone across the top. However, repeatedly poking the button, only fires 13 of the 16 droppers. The three bottom droppers next to the yellow wool do not fire.

Any idea why this might be?  There is no redstone within several blocks of the droppers.  Sometimes I wire this up, in slightly different contexts, and get all 16 to fire, sometimes just 15 ....  Is there a simple explanation as to why this wiring scheme will not work?  I'd hoped to do this, so I could put a hopper filling system on the back end, filling all these droppers, so I wanted to avoid wiring them from the back, and wanted to just do the top...

Edit:  Here's the proposed hopper filling system.  This will be connected to a massive farm, so this is in fact "efficient" for my needs.

[image]

Comment: Um, could you fix something. I think you mean droppers rather than hoppers.

Comment: How fast are you clicking the button?

Comment: @Ben I could though 1) I've been explicitly discouraged in doing so and 2) I'm using my iPod atm which is horrible for editing.

Comment: Gentelmen.  Thank you.  I have no idea what brain fart occurred that I typed HOPPER everywhere instead of DROPPER.  Must be too late local time.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. It might be just that you are pressing the button too quickly before the hoppers can fill up the whole droppers.

Comment: @QbsidianH20 I'm running 1.8.9.  I can do this in my creative and survival worlds.  I'm not sure what you mean by "pressing the button too quickly" as buttons do what they do.  Same behavior occurs with levers.  This happens slightly differently on NS vs. EW lines of droppers.

Comment: @QbsidianH20 I have found that you need to test thism ultiple times.  The first couple of times, due to adjacent block updates, it appears the droppers will all fire one or two times, but then they don't fire.  Ultimately I believe this to be a bug in 1.8.9.

Comment: Make sure the bug is reported on [bugs.mojang.com](https://bugs.mojang.com/issues/?jql=project+%3D+MC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, i tried your system in my redstone world, and i managed to reproduce the problem.

In fact, some droppers randomly do not shoot. Most of the times the same three, but not always. I thought it was some kind of issue related to some block upload detection...

But not worry my friend, i managed to fixed it! Just a line of repeaters and it's done.Not so elegant, but it works fine. See this.

[image]

Now it shoots exactly 16 items each time the button is pressed :)

May i take your time for a longer answer?

First, i couldn't reproduce your problem, as stated before by @QbsidianH20
Second, after your first filling of the droppers, seeing your hoppers configuration, you will gradually start to make useless the top ones, then gradually the bottom ones too, starting from the far right (facing the front of the droppers), eventually ending with only the first one or two shooting. Tis is because of the way hoppers work, prioritizing vertical transfer over horizzontal.

This is true for each hopper system with only one input of items, like i see in your configuration. 
Moreover, hoppers can only transfer items at a pace of 2.5 per second, making that huge set of droppers completely wasted, sadly.

If you have more items input from different hopper chains, i will suggest you to make a single dropper with clock for each input, maximizing your efficiency both of resources and time.

With your permission, i will proceed to illustrate.

First case: ONE INPUT

[image]

I copied your configuration. You can see after a while only the first dropper fires, but they are all powered! Fact is, he is the only one with something inside to fire. Poor guy.

Possible solution for one input:

[image]

Mono input, mono dropper. The clock on its back is a pretty nice one, only triggers when something's actually inside, staying off when empty. And still quite fast.

If you have a HUGE and i mean reeally huge amount of items to funnel, i suggest to simply copy this configuration as many times as needed.

Like this:

[image]

You can see THREE INPUTS of items into three different droppers, each one with its own clock to minimize unnecessary ticks.
For each dropper we have five hopper lines, all converging into one input.

I have a humongous mob farm with a ridiculous amount of item drop per second, and this is my system. Three droppers don't even need to work all the time.

I hope i managed to help you, good luck building the rest of your farm! ;)

My farm and the funnels for sauce, with the firing mechanism (you can see it shooting items in the drop pool below, in order to be sorted).

[image]
[image]

Comment: The redstone line in my contraption will mostly be off.  It will only be shooting once every 30 seconds or so.  So, all this analysis, while interesting, is inapplicable to my situation.  My problem is the fact that I can't dispense 16 items from my 16 droppers with a single redstone activation.  The loading system is not a problem at all.

Comment: Oh, i see... well, i tried again in my redstone world, and i managed to see the problem! in fact, some droppers randomly do not shoot. Most of the times the same three, but not always. I thought it was some kind of issue related to some block upload detection... but not worry my friend, i  managed to fixed it. Just a line of repeaters and it's done. See here: http://imgur.com/gallery/Enanedr/new
Now it shoots exactly 16 items each time the button is pressed :)

Comment: Most impressive building!!  Please post your final comment  (which is really an answer) as your first answer, with the rest being an aside, and I'll gladly accept your answer.

Comment: I think ultimately this is a bug, would you agree?

Comment: Ok, sure, i'll edit it right away.
At any rate, yes, i think it's a bug related to the in-game mechanics related to droppers & dispenser power/fire response
It is curious to note that the malfunctioning droppers were the same in both our simulation, only mirrored (i had the input on the right side)
This shows the problem is systematic and not an isolated case.